# Need a Way to Test a user against remote server using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sitescope

My only objective is to validate the user account against bunch servers. I am using below commands to do it.

```
$creds2= Get-Credential
$servers = Get-Content ('C:\Users\vishnuvardhan.chapal\Documents\Widnows Servers success in 139 and 445.txt')
$servers | ForEach-Object {Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $_ -Credential $creds2} | Out-GridView
```

Here, I am encountering two problems.

1) In the Grid view, I am just getting the hostname but without FQDN like shown in below screenshot.

[image: Screen shot of the oupput]

2) Above screen is only for succeeded servers and for failed ones (for the servers, where authentication is failing) I am getting the output in Powershell window like below screen.

[image]

Now, my goal is to combine both the output's in at single place. Is it possible? If yes, How to do it? Please shed some light to it.

Apart from above is there any way to test it more easily, i mean a direct command to test the user authentication against a remote server??

***FYI...My only goal for this exercise is to validate user authentication not to get some details from a remote computer.***

Comment: Take a look at https://ss64.com/ps/try.html for the error handling. I don't know about single computers, but there are methods to validate credentials against a domain in .Net that you can run in Powershell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Out-GridView` is not a good way to handle these things. Recommended to convert that into JSON or some kind of a format and then parse it in files or however you wish to. 
There are multiple ways to check that but error handling will solve your issue:

```
try
{
    $creds2= Get-Credential
    $servers = Get-Content ('C:\Users\vishnuvardhan.chapal\Documents\Widnows Servers success in 139 and 445.txt')
    $servers 

    foreach($server in $servers)
    {
        try
        {
        Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Server -Credential $creds2
        }
        catch
        {
        "Error in accessing the server - $Server with the given credential. Kindly validate."
        }
    }
}
catch
{
$_.Exception.Message
}
```

So within the loop also I have added a try catch because if one server is failing, it will proceed with the next server from the list and that will capture the error with server name along with the message.

Hope it helps.